# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no TaSESDK in java.library.path

Tags: java

I have a TaSESDK.so

Dockerfile

```
FROM  java:8 
ADD app.jar /app.jar
ADD TaSESDK.so /javaLib/TaSESDK.so
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java -jar -Djava.library.path=/javaLib  /app.jar"]
```

when I log the java.library.path  it print "/javaLib"

but stil can not find library

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[12:23:38:316] [ERROR] - org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:826) - Application run failed
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no TaSESDK in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at com.newland.rentalroom.listener.TaSESDKCommandLineRunner.run(TaSESDKCommandLineRunner.java:49) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at com.newland.rentalroom.AppApplication.main(AppApplication.java:16) [classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [app.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [app.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [app.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597) [app.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Answer (score 0):

i slove the problem

loadLibrary

```
System.loadLibrary("TaSESDK");
```

i never change this code
run successfully in windows but fail in linux docker

```
javaLib
                |-->TaSESDK.so
                |-->TaSESDK.dll
```

the problem is  libTaSESDK.so

```
|-->javaLib 
                |-->TaSESDK.dll
                |-->libTaSESDK.so
```

in linux  must add lib prefix